# Apps script: map not returning expected value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array of objects that looks like:

```
var objArray = [
  {
    " #": "4596",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/12/20",
    " County": "Los Angeles County",
    " State": "California",
    " Acres": "2.49",
    " Eager": "Low",
  },
  {
    " #": "4588",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/11/20",
    " County": "Towns County",
    " State": "Georgia",
    " Acres": "3.00",
    " Eager": "High",
  },
  ....
];
```

I'm trying to put together an array of the indexes ('#');

So far I have:

```
let indexes = objArray.forEach(function (rowObj) {
  Object.keys(rowObj).map(function (key) {
    if (key.includes("#")) {
      var v = rowObj[key];
      Logger.log(v); // abc
      return v;
    }
  });
});

Logger.log(indexes); // abc
```

output:

```
[20-06-13 20:43:33:320 EDT] 4547
[20-06-13 20:43:33:324 EDT] 4546
[20-06-13 20:43:33:329 EDT] 4545
[20-06-13 20:43:33:450 EDT] 4543
[20-06-13 20:43:33:453 EDT] 4542
[20-06-13 20:43:33:456 EDT] 4540
[20-06-13 20:43:33:459 EDT] 4538
```

This is producing:

```
[20-06-13 20:43:33:462 EDT] null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key you are looking for is always `#` and if it is present in all objects you could simplify the logic using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Please look at the following example

```js
const objArray = [
  {
    " #": "4596",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/12/20",
    " County": "Los Angeles County",
    " State": "California",
    " Acres": "2.49",
    " Eager": "Low",
  },
  {
    " #": "4588",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/11/20",
    " County": "Towns County",
    " State": "Georgia",
    " Acres": "3.00",
    " Eager": "High",
  },
];

const output = objArray.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => [...previousValue, currentValue[" #"]],
  []
);

console.log(output)
```

Update 0

Reduce you use it when you need to compact the content of an array, its operation is very similar to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in that they use a callback function that is executed in each entry of the array, the difference is that it reduces takes as `initialValue` argument which you update in each iteration.

For example, this is the same version without the shortcuts that allow you to use the arrow functions, `previousValue` corresponds to the initialValue, and `currentValue` to the object in each iteration. So in each iteration you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the content of previousValue  and get and attach the value of the `#` property of currentValue

Run the example so you can see the values of the previousValue in each iteration

```js
const objArray = [
  {
    " #": "4596",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/12/20",
    " County": "Los Angeles County",
    " State": "California",
    " Acres": "2.49",
    " Eager": "Low",
  },
  {
    " #": "4588",
    " E": "Yes",
    " Date": "06/11/20",
    " County": "Towns County",
    " State": "Georgia",
    " Acres": "3.00",
    " Eager": "High",
  },
];

const output = objArray.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  console.log(previousValue);
  previousValue = [...previousValue, currentValue[" #"]];

  return previousValue;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

This [post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reduce-f47a7da511a9/) was the first I read about reduce, it explains the concept in a practical and simple way. I recommend your reading. Cheers

Comment: Thank you - I'm fairly new to js and reduce. Would you mind explaining what you've done here?

Comment: I apologize , its a great explanation. I'm familiar and have used reduce before, but at a beginning level as in your explanation. I'm less clear about the function you are using - (previousValue, currentValue) => [...previousValue, currentValue[" #"]] -  Is previous value the accumulator?

Comment: I understand. Yes previousValue is the accumulator. About `[...previousValue, currentValue[" #"]]` I am using spread syntax to expand the current accumulator in a new array plus the value of currentValue in property ` #`

Comment: @LDN - the `[...sourceArray, value]` is just a more concise way to right `sourceArray.concat([ value ])` since ES6 came around (see [spread in array literas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals))

Answer (score 6):

As a supplementary answer:

You can do this even simpler and faster.

```js
const values = [
  { " #": "4596", " E": "Yes"},
  { " #": "4597", " E": "No"},
  { " #": "4598", " E": "Maybe"},
]

const indices = values.map(({ " #" : id }) => id);

console.log(indices);
```

Please, note that callback to `map()` method should be deterministic to acheive a consistent result.

**Actual problem**

Check the documentation on `forEach()` method - it is intended for producing side-effects and therefore returns `void` (literally no value), hence the last `Logger.log(indexes);` issue.

**Useful links**

1. `map()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. Arrow functions [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
3. `forEach()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Its a great idea, but when I run it in apps script I get:  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: Does the `#` comes prefixed with whitespace in your real code? Could tou show how you implemented the suggestion?

Comment: You have to make sure the following is true: 1. `map` is called directly on the array of objects (`objArray`). 2. The `" #"` key consists exactly of whitespace and hash chars. 3. V8 runtime is enabled (the same goes for Mario's answer, btw)

Answer (score 2):

I think your return in the middle of the loop was the problem.  Other than that it's okay works fine.

This works for me:

```
function functest() {
  var objArray =[{" #":"4596"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/12/20"," County":"Los Angeles County"," State":"California"," Acres":"2.49"," Eager":"Low"},
                 {" #":"4588"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/11/20"," County":"Towns County"," State":"Georgia"," Acres":"3.00"," Eager":"High"},
                 {" #":"4596"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/12/20"," County":"Los Angeles County"," State":"California"," Acres":"2.49"," Eager":"Low"},
                 {" #":"4588"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/11/20"," County":"Towns County"," State":"Georgia"," Acres":"3.00"," Eager":"High"},
                 {" #":"4596"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/12/20"," County":"Los Angeles County"," State":"California"," Acres":"2.49"," Eager":"Low"},
                 {" #":"4588"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/11/20"," County":"Towns County"," State":"Georgia"," Acres":"3.00"," Eager":"High"},
                 {" #":"4596"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/12/20"," County":"Los Angeles County"," State":"California"," Acres":"2.49"," Eager":"Low"},
                 {" #":"4588"," E":"Yes"," Date":"06/11/20"," County":"Towns County"," State":"Georgia"," Acres":"3.00"," Eager":"High"}];
  var oA=[];
  let indexes=objArray.forEach(function(rowObj) {
    Object.keys(rowObj).map(function(key) {
      if (key.includes('#') ) {
        var v = rowObj[key];
        oA.push(v);
      }
    });
  });
  Logger.log(oA);
}//[4596, 4588, 4596, 4588, 4596, 4588, 4596, 4588]
```

Comment: I find this a lot quicker to use to view results: `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(oA.join('<br />')), "Display Results");`